# Evaluate x given the equation $x + \sqrt x = \sqrt 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given:        $x + \sqrt x = \sqrt 3$
Evaluate:         $x^3 - 1 / x^3$

Comment: Are you sure they didn't mean $x+x^{-1}=\sqrt 3$?

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff . But even that will not ease the calculation right ? as we have only the form $ a^3 - b^3 $

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam Yes it will, since  $${x^3} + {x^{ - 3}} = {\left( {x + {x^{ - 1}}} \right)^3} - 3\left( {x + {x^{ - 1}}} \right)$$

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff . But asked is $x^3 - x^{-3}$ right ? Am i missing something ?

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam Whoops! You can work out something similar, I got the signs wrong, sorry.

Comment: Sorry typo error, Peter is right, it should be $x + x^-1 = \sqrt {3}$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: we can solve $x+\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{3}$, using the quadratic formula.  Just use $\sqrt{x}$ as the variable.

From there, it's just plugging in those values for $x$ into the second equation.

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

put $x=y^2$ and solve it by quadratic formula